# How to get image size from base 64 string in php

Tags: php, file-upload, base64

I am getting the base 64 for string for image I have to move in folder and store the image path in database but I have to limit the file size.How can I do this:

My code for generate image from base 64 string is like:

```
/** if image is attached with request **/
 $Image = "MyBase64StringHere";
 list($type, $Image) = explode(';', $Image);
 list(, $Image)      = explode(',', $Image);

/** decode the base 64 image **/
 $Image = base64_decode($Image);

I have tried to get image size like:
$size =  getimagesize($Image);
```

But from this am getting file width and height.Can someone tell me how can I get file size from this.Thanks

Comment: Your `$path` contains relative path, can you please try with absolute path - like `http://www.example.com/uploads/....jpg`.

Comment: `strlen($Image)` will work?

Comment: @Lashane, `strlen` is used for getting string length. OP need image size.

Comment: @prava OP wants file size, which equals to string length in this case

Comment: But I want to validate image size before moving to folder,Is it possible ?

Comment: @Randhir, if you are using PHP 5.4, then please check with this method - `getimagesizefromstring()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check this :

After decoding, try with this : `getimagesizefromstring()`, if you are with `PHP 5.4`, if using `PHP 5.3`, then you can check with the following method.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('getimagesizefromstring')) {
    function getimagesizefromstring($data)
    {
        $uri = 'data://application/octet-stream;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        return getimagesize($uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `getimagesize()` function should just work with Data URI as well:

```
$Image = "MyBase64StringHere";
$size = getimagesize($Image);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since that the base-64 algorithm **increases** the image size up to **33%**, i strongly recommend you to use **this way**:

```
$size = (int)(strlen(rtrim($image, '=')) * 0.75); // in byte
```

Comment: This is a very simple solution, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try this one get file size in Bytes, KB, MB..

```
public function getBase64ImageSize($base64Image){ //return memory size in B, KB, MB
    try{
        $size_in_bytes = (int) (strlen(rtrim($base64Image, '=')) * 3 / 4);
        $size_in_kb    = $size_in_bytes / 1024;
        $size_in_mb    = $size_in_kb / 1024;

        return $size_in_mb;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        return $e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea to get image size before moving to folder is not good.Then I decided to move image to a temporary folder and get the size using image path and then validate image size.With this I can easily validate image size and prevent it to store in database if size limit exceeds.Thanks every one for their time.

My updated code is like:

```
/** if image is attached with request **/
$Image = "Yourbase64StringHere";
list($type, $Image) = explode(';', $Image);
list(, $Image)      = explode(',', $Image);

/** decode the base 64 image **/
$Image = base64_decode($Image);

/* move image to temp folder */
$TempPath = 'temp/'.time().".jpg";
file_put_contents($TempPath, $Image);

$ImageSize = filesize($TempPath);/* get the image size */

if($ImageSize < 83889000){ /* limit size to 10 mb */

/** move the uploaded image **/
$path = 'uploads/'.time().".jpg";
file_put_contents($path, $Image);

$Image = $path;
/** get the image path and store in database **/

unlink($TempPath);/* delete the temporay file */

}else{

unlink($TempPath);/* delete the temporay file */

/** image size limit exceded **/

}
```