# How do I resize an image that I echo from my SQL database

Tags: php, css, image, resize

I am using the php code below to echo an image from mysql database, please help me show how can I set the width and height of the image?

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['venueimage']) . '"/>';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image size from base 64 string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645830/how-to-get-image-size-from-base-64-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SQL, it's a matter of CSS.

The CSS rules you need are `width` and `height`, and you can specify them either in the tag itself

```
echo '<img style="width: x; height: y" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['venueimage']) . '"/>';
```

or in a `style` tag in your `header` section

```
echo '<style type="text/css">
         #venue{
             width: x;
             height: y;
         }
      </style>'

...

echo '<img id="venue" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['venueimage']) . '"/>';
```

or even in a separate file

```
yourStyle.css
#venue{
    width: x;
    height: y;
}

yourPHPfile.php
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourStyle.css" />';

...

echo '<img id="venue" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['venueimage']) . '"/>';
```

You can read more about how CSS works and the different places it can be placed [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import) (and in many other places, you can just search "CSS where").

Comment: thanks alot this has really worked for me,My problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, on simple solution is to echo the image with proper styling, something like this

```
echo '<img style="width: 500px; height: 200px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['venueimage']) . '"/>';
```

Another solution is to add a class or an ID to your image and then create a CSS rule to style it

```
echo '<img id="foo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['venueimage']) . '"/>';
```

And in your CSS

```
#foo{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```